# java - object initialization syntax: someVar = (SomeClass[]) Object[aVariable]

Tags: java

In the following code snippet from https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/44st/BinarySearchST.java.html
what does `keys = (Key[]) new Comparable[initCapacity];` do?

```
public class BinarySearchST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private static final int INIT_SIZE = 8;

    private Value[] vals;    // symbol table values
    private Key[] keys;      // symbol table keys
    private int n = 0;       // number of elements

    public BinarySearchST() {
        this(INIT_SIZE);
    }

    public BinarySearchST(int initCapacity) {
        vals = (Value[]) new Object[initCapacity];
        keys = (Key[]) new Comparable[initCapacity];
    } ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it down like this:

Initialize a `new Object` array of size `initCapacity`

```
Object [] someValues = new Object[initCapacity];
Comparable [] someComparable = new Comparable[initCapacity];
```

Then typecast the array to an array of type `Value`

```
vals = (Value[]) someValues;
keys = (Keys[]) someComparable;
```

Your statement above is doing these operations on single lines.
Keep in mind you have declared `vals` as an array of `Values` and `keys` as an array of `Keys`.

Comment: This may answer "what does x do?" but fails to mention anything about generic types. I'm worried that this answer may confuse people into thinking they can cast normally typed arrays to a subtype such as Integer[] iArr = (Integer[]) new Number[1];

Comment: @xtratic You can't teach people everything in a single answer, you provide concrete explanation for what they ask, otherwise there would be answers containing well over hundreds of lines of text, they have books for that.

Comment: My concern is less about teaching everything in a single answer and more about avoiding confusion for people who are not Java veterans. All it might take to help avoid confusion is emphasizing "generic type Value" and "generic type Key".

Comment: The question specifically asked about the syntax `someVar = (SomeClass[]) Object[aVariable]`.  While I think it is worthwhile to note that the class uses generic types, I felt it was outside the scope.  I agree some level of education around generics helps to understand the entire code described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `Key` is a generic type. and specifically it is some type that extends `Comparable`.

**Since you can't create an array of a generic type because of type erasure**, you need to create an array of a supertype/interface of that generic type. In this case we know that `Comparable` is an interface of the generic type `Key`, so an array of `Comparables` is created in memory, then cast to the generic type `Key`

Here's more examples (also implement comparable):

```
static <T extends Comparable> T[] genericMethod(T someObj) {
    T[] arrayOfTypeT = (T[]) new Comparable[1];
    arrayOfTypeT[0] = someObj;
    return arrayOfTypeT;
}

// String extends Comparable
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arrayOfString = genericMethod("A string");
    Integer[] arrayOfInt = genericMethod(new Integer(1));

    // this one doesn't compile, because it doesn't extend Comparable
    Object[] arrayOfObject = genericMethod(new Object());
}
```